# What data can I collect with oAuth for Twitter?

Tags: twitter, authentication, oauth

I'm looking to integrate a twitter login into my site.  I've used the developer link for FB to see what data can be collected.  I'd like to know what data I can retrieve from twitter once a user logs in with twitter from my site?

Answer (score 0):

A full list of API endpoints is available here on the [Twitter dev site](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).

[account/verify_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials) would be the most basic one to start with as it is information about the authenticated user.